# Smart-table, the filter clean the table

Tags: jquery, angularjs, smart-table

With the code below (controller and html page), I see the table it's ok. But the filter does not work. When I type something in the filter :

1. All the datas disappear (even if the filter match with some records)
2. When I clean the filter not come back

Any idea ?

Thanks,

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('customerListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

    getCustomers = function () {
        var url = '......';

        $http({ method: 'GET', url: url })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.customers = data.Customers;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        });

    };

    $scope.customers = getCustomers();

}]);

<table st-table="customers" st-safe-src="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th st-sort="FirstName">FirstName</th>
            <th st-sort="LastName">LastName</th>
            <th st-sort="Code">Code</th>
            <th st-sort="Email">Email</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4"><input st-search="" class="form-control" placeholder="global search ..." type="text" /></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in customers">
            <td>{{row.FirstName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.LastName}}</td>
            <td>{{row.Code}}</td>
            <td>{{row.Email}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Update 1 :
I added the code below but now change.

```
$scope.customers = getCustomers();
$scope.rowCollection = $scope.customers;
```

Comment: read the docs for `st-safe-src`. You need 2 collections and your `st-table` is not set

Comment: Added code as show in Update 1 but no change

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still looking for an answer.
By doing this `$scope.rowCollection = $scope.customers;` you keep a reference to `$scope.customers`.

If I'm right, you have to make a copy of you customers datas by doing something like this:

```
var yourCustomersData = getCustomers();
$scope.customers = angular.copy(yourCustomersData); // st-table
$scope.rowCollection = angular.copy(yourCustomersData); // st-safe-src
```

I think it'll work like that.

Answer (score 0):

you just confused what is st-table and st-safe-src ,
st-table is a temporary data when you made a search or filter your data grid the smart-table filter the main data from st-safe-src and then assign to st-table temporary data source

here you don't want to assign data to st-table sperately because its an optional, Initially smart table look for it and filter the data then assign to that.

In your code i just change the line :

In your Js, i saw something strange there.
Your Code :

```
$scope.customers = getCustomers();
```

In here you assign non returnable function to your data source. So your datasource may gets undefined. So I just change that one line.

```
getCustomers();
```

In Your HTML :

```
<table st-table="tempCollection" st-safe-src="customers" class="table table-striped">
```

In Your Js Code :

```
    angular.module('myApp').controller('customerListController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

    getCustomers = function () {
        var url = '......';

        $http({ method: 'GET', url: url })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.customers = data.Customers; // st-safe-src
            //no need to assign st-table
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        });

    };

    getCustomers();

}]);
```